# Replace imm32.dll file in Wine

Tags: wine

For Wine, I have a custom-built imm32.dll.so file that I would like to override with a certain application.  Replacing the built-in DLL under /usr/lib32/wine/ works, but I don't want to override the DLL for all my Wine programs.  I only want to override one application that's in it's own WINEPREFIX.

The winecfg is set to override imm32 with builtin only.  I've tried placing the DLL under the system32 and in the same directory as the application without any success.  I've also tried setting the WINEDLLPATH path with no success.  Nothing seems to work other than copying the imm32.dll.so file to /usr/lib32/wine.